# Using an Element by its ID without declaring ID first

Tags: jquery, getelementbyid

I'm trying to use an element by its ID without explicitly creating a reference to it.

http://jsfiddle.net/D8A8P/

```
<button id="btn-1">Show Content A</button>
<button id="btn-2">Show Content B</button>
<button id="btn-3">Show Content C</button>

<div id="content-1">Fancy Pants</div>
<div id="content-2">Small Town</div>
<div id="content-3">Cheap Whiskey</div>
```

If a user clicks on a btn, I want to know which one was clicked.

```
$( ??? ).on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.id);
});

// If user clicks on btn-1
// console: "btn-1"

// If user clicks on btn-2
// console: "btn-2"
```

Comment: For what it's worth, you [don't need JavaScript for this](http://jsfiddle.net/D8A8P/5/).

Comment: This is really neat. This was just a tibbit of what I'm working on, but I had no idea CSS could do that...

Comment: I'm curious. Is there a way to close any visible divs when a new button is clicked? That's some functionality I'm working on in jQuery.

Comment: I presume you mean with CSS? This would require changing the *state* of general sibling input elements, which is not possible solely with CSS.

Comment: I meant CSS. Thanks for responding. I'm still amazed CSS can do that much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [`attribute starts with selector`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/),

```
$("[id^='btn-']").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.id);
});
```

Comment: Thank you. This works. I've been trying to Google/SO this for 45 mins and no luck. You're the best!

Comment: "attribute starts with selector" - thanks for mentioning that.

Comment: Why does it only need one bracket ("[") and not both? Specs say "jQuery( "[attribute^='value']" )"

Comment: Haha. I thought one bracket was a standard practice, because it was working *just fine* in jsfiddle ;) thanks for editing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`attribute starts with selector`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/). Try this:

```
$("button[id^='btn-']").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/D8A8P/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

Your example code only shows buttons, so the handler could simply be applied to all buttons:

```
$('button').on('click', function (e) {
    console.log(this.id);
});
```

A simple selector should be preferred over one that uses `[id^=...` because the latter will **search the whole** document.

Comment: I never thought that would have worked... interesting. Thanks.

Comment: @Sophisticake Simpler is typically better when you're working with jQuery :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("button[id^='btn-']").on("click", function (e) {
    console.log($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

there is no need to specify preventDefault. botton does not have any default functional action

Comment: `id` is a property and not an attribute. Also, the gist of this answer has been given multiple times.